# Rep-cap hitting too early?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit

Today I earned only 170 rep from upvotes:

[image: rep stats]

But still I got an upvote on one of my questions that did not count. How come?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is your question, which is a [Community Wiki question now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967079/special-characters-in-content-disposition-filename).

No rep for those...

Comment: Ah - did not notice that.

Comment: I have a few CW posts on SO, so I am kinda used to that ;)

Comment: I did not edit the post for almost a year. How come it turned into CW **now**?

Comment: It did so in October of last year @juergend.

Comment: @juergend - After enough self-edits it happens. If you look at the revision history, revision 12 (the latest one) has the following comment: `[made Community Wiki by juergen d editing at least 10 times]`